# How can I get a reference to standard input from assembly on a mac?

Tags: macos, assembly, clang, x86-64

I'm following along in some books on assembler and find that they happily use `fprintf` with `stdout`.  They simply reference `stdout` as a known symbol.  I tried to do that in my code, and the linker complains that stdout is not found.  I tried variation on spelling including a leading underscore.  I also disassembled `printf`.  It sets up a call to `vfprintf` using the following line:

```
leaq   0x41879948(%rip), %rax    ; __stdoutp
```

So it seems like I should be able to do something like:

```
leaq __stdoutp(%rip), %rdi
```

Didn't work.  Linker complains of undefined symbol.  Tried with variations.  Left off the p suffix, one or both of the underscores.  Nothing worked.

Any ideas, or insider knowledge I can follow to access to this symbol?

Comment: `fprintf(stdout, ...)` takes the *value* of `FILE *stdout`, which is a pointer it has to load from memory.  You're doing `fprintf(&stdout, ...)`.  In C, using the name of a variable is implicitly the contents of memory at its address, except for arrays.

Comment: But if the standard header defines a value for `stdout = &something`, then yeah it could be a compile-time constant on some implementation, with an underscore-prefixed name like you're seeing.  You should look at the compiler-generated asm (`clang -S`) to see what it actually does, in a form *you* could use yourself, if you link against the same libraries, instead of the basic `mov _stdout(%rip), %rdi` that you'd naively expect from the C source with MacOS's leading-underscore convention.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @PeterCordes suggestion of looking at the compiler generated asm, I wrote a c program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { fprintf(stdout, "Hello, world!\n"); }
```

ran `clang -S main.c` on it, and had a look at the asm.  Here's how clang generated asm is accessing the stdout global

```
    movq    ___stdoutp@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
    movq    (%rax), %rdi
```

Turns out this is stated in the ABI (section 3.5.4)

> Position-independent code cannot contain absolute address. To access a *global symbol* the address of the symbol has to be loaded from the Global Offset Table. The address of
> the entry in the GOT can be obtained with a %rip-relative instruction in the small model.

`stdout` in the c code refers to the `__stdoutp` symbol.  This becomes `___stdoutp` in assembler, because macosx.  Similar to how `main` is `_main`.

ABI section 5.2 explains GOT this way

> Global offset tables hold absolute addresses in private data, thus making the addresses available without compromising the position-independence and shareability of a program’s text.

Comment: Ok, so this is basically the opposite of what it looked like in the question.  Instead of being able to `lea` instead of loading a global variable, there's actually an *extra* level of indirection through the GOT to get the address of the global variable `__stdoutp`, then load it.  You'd expect asm like that with `gcc -fPIC` where symbol interposition is possible, but normally the main executable can directly access global vars.

Comment: I also don't know why MacOS C headers would define `stdout` as an alias for `__stdoutp` instead of using its normal name.  Maybe they want to use static storage in the library, so libc can reference `stdout` more cheaply for calls that use it implicitly (like `printf`), so inside libc maybe it can compile to just `lea` or `mov ___stdoutp(%rip), %rdi`, and everything else has to do through the GOT because the relative position won't be a link-time constant or fit in a `rel32` 32-bit displacement.